# Add a line break javascript

Tags: reactjs

How do I add a line break into my `ModalBodContent` react component?

```
<ModalMain
  ModalBodyContent={`New account created. Enrolment email sent. \n\n Name: ${firstName} ${lastName} \n email: ${email}`}
/>
```

Comment: `<br>`? `\n`? .

Comment: yes, the \n doesn't work and if I use <br /> it appears as text.

Comment: Then check `ModalMain` documentation about how they suggest to add new lines.

Comment: It's my component.

Comment: Why are you passing a string, if you want html elements to happen? Pass (the React equivalent of) an HTML element: `let bcontent = <div>...</div>; ...; <ModalMain ModalBodyContent={bcontent}/>` and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

You can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) inside of your `<ModalMain/>`

```
function render() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `New account created. Enrolment email sent. \n\n Name: ${firstName} ${lastName} \n email: ${email}`}} />;
}
```

Or you can pass `ModalBodyContent` as an element, and render it accordingly:

```
<ModalMain
  ModalBodyContent={
    <div>
      New account created. Enrolment email sent. 
      <br/><br/>
      Name: {firstName} {lastName} 
      <br/>
      email: {email}
    </div>
  }
/>
```

*Can also do this:*

```
<ModalMain>
  <div>
    New account created. Enrolment email sent. 
    <br/><br/>
    Name: {firstName} {lastName} 
    <br/>
    email: {email}
  </div>
</ModalMain>
```

Answer (score 2):

your code perfectly break string line but you need to use CSS style `white-space: pre-wrap;` in you HTML element where you render that string line.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're expecting to be passed into `ModalBodyContent`.

If you use this prop as a string, well, there's pretty well nothing you can do. But if you use it as a `React.ReactNode`, then you can pass there not only a string, but also any JSX, including, for example, `React.Fragment`:

```
<ModalMain
  ModalBodyContent={(
    <React.Fragment>
      New account created. Enrolment email sent.
      <br/>
      <br/>
      {`Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}`}
      <br/>
      {`email: ${email}`}
    </React.Fragment>
/>
```

To use the component this way, internals of `ModalMain` should be something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    // some complex jsx, possibly...
    {this.props.ModalContent}
    // anything else...;
  )
}
```